# How to find text element inside parent element in SVG dynamically?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have 2 different SVG structure:

```
// This is the 1st structure
<g id="CDT-B6-2">
  <path id="CDT-B6-box" class="fil11"/>
  <text x="936" y="540" id="CDT-B6-text" class="fil13 fnt31">888</text>
</g>

// This is the 2nd structure
<g id="CDT-B6-2">
  <path id="CDT-B6-box" class="fil11"/>
  <g transform="matrix(0.987916 0 0 1 301.975 450.301)">
    <text x="936" y="540" id="CDT-B6-text" class="fil13 fnt31">888</text>
  </g>
</g>
```

Currently I have this code: `document.querySelectorAll("text[id$='CDT-B6-2'")` but it's only applicable from the 1st structure. I cannot find the text element from the 2nd structure.

Comment: those are in different document. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: no its not. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Don't you mean to look for ID CDT-B6-text rather than CDT-B6-2?

Comment: With the current selector, nothing will get selected from either SVG structure.

Comment: yup. I only use the CDT-B6-2 to hide the whole elements, but I also need to get text element inside CDT-B6-2 to update textContent @seesharper

Comment: I'm not getting it. You have a text element with an ID, which as we discussed is unique. So why not just select the text element by ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have multiple ID's with the same name as ids must be unique. Change them to classes if you will have the same name for the selectors.

Just target the *`text`* selector like this `const selector = document.querySelectorAll('.CDT-B6-2 text')`.

Though the following would give you the exact same result... `const selector = document.querySelectorAll('.CDT-B6-text')`.

```js
const selector = document.querySelectorAll('.CDT-B6-2 text')


selector.forEach(textNode => {
  console.log(textNode)
})
```

```html
// This is the 1st structure
<g class="CDT-B6-2">
  <path class="CDT-B6-box fil11" />
  <text x="936" y="540" class="CDT-B6-text fil13 fnt31">888</text>
</g>

// This is the 2nd structure
<g class="CDT-B6-2">
  <path class="CDT-B6-box fil11" />
  <g transform="matrix(0.987916 0 0 1 301.975 450.301)">
    <text x="936" y="540" class="CDT-B6-text fil13 fnt31">999</text>
  </g>
</g>
```

NOTE: in changing the multiple id's I initially just changed the duplicate ***id*** attribute to a ***class*** attribute, creating two ***class*** attributes in the element `<div class="someclass" class="anotherclass">`. This is incorrect, make sure your classes all live under one `class` attribute. `<div class="someclass anotherclass">`

Comment: You are welcome ;) glad to help... Make sure to note the ID mention, ID's must be unique per each selector, you should not repeat ID's in the same document. Best, and happy coding... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: Your duplicate ``class`` on one element are incorrect. Duplicate IDs on the other hand do have a purpose, but only Web developers who have been around since early Internet Explorer days understand. IDs create **global** variables in every Browser (because every browser vendor had to copy IE behavior, otherwise some IE sites would not function) But only use duplicate IDs in prototyping... because every Web code slinger with less then 20 years Web development under the belt won't understand.

Comment: And here is the explanation on duplicate IDs being part of the HTML standard: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/07/19/dom-element-references-as-global-variables/

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes the duplicate class attribute is indeed incorrect as I changed their ID to a class and overlooked that part thank you for bringing it to my attention.